# Review "First Posts" audit failed on commenting

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits, first-post-review

I was reviewing first posts when I came along this post: [Replace the string of special characters in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44715420/replace-the-string-of-special-characters-in-c-sharp)
I wanted to go ahead and comment giving suggestions to use `StringBuilder` instead of `string`. As soon as I tried to comment I got an alert saying this was an audit and I failed. 
How is giving a helpful comment to a good question failing an audit? I find it absurd and counter-intuitive to only comment on low-quality posts and refrain from any helpful comments if it is a high-quality post.

Comment: Your comment would have been superfluous, as [that comment already exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44715420/replace-the-string-of-special-characters-in-c-sharp#comment76427291_44715420).

Comment: But you don't see comments, upvotes or the correct username at times in audit questions. So surely I wasn't aware of similar comments. The question here is not about superfluous comments, but why would any comment result in a failed audit.

Comment: Well a `StringBuilder` isn't actually an appropriate tool for that job in the first place, so there's that.

Comment: @Servy I will repeat. It is not about whether my comment is the accurate solution. It is about being Audits failing if you comment. So there isn't that

Comment: @Servy `Stringbuilder` does help in better performance [String.Replace() vs. StringBuilder.Replace()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6524918/3110695)

Comment: @FortyTwo And yet it's still notably worse than numerous other options presented as answers.  Being a better solution than something else that's a bad solution doesn't make it a good solution.

Comment: @Servy I was proposing a comment and not an answer. Irrespective of the quality of the comment why would my audit fail? That is my issue.

Comment: I can explain to you *why* this action failed the audit, and that's because there was nothing wrong with the question and so you shouldn't have wanted to add a moderation comment to it. Of course, you'll argue that you *weren't* adding a moderation comment, but that misses the point. The purpose of the review queues is to moderate posts, so the interface is designed around that, and if you try to add a comment to something that doesn't need to be moderated (taken as fact, because it's an audit), then the system fails you. You can *disagree* with that design, and many do, but it is what it is.